# How to specify cookies stored in file with perl module LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, lwp

I have the following piece of code that uses cookies collected from another perl program to log into a sharepoint website using the perl module LWP::UserAgent.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use HTTP::CookieJar::LWP ();
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $resultXML='C:\Docs\Result.txt';
my $url="https://[mydomain].sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo";
        
my $cookie_jar_obj = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookie_jar_obj->load( $resultXML );
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$lwp->cookie_jar( $cookie_jar_obj ); 
        
print $lwp->cookie_jar->as_string() . "\n";

my $response = $lwp->request(POST $url);
print $response->content . "\n";
```

Where the file stored in the variable $resultXML contains the following cookie information:

```
#LWP-Cookies-1.0
Set-Cookie3:rtFa=UROIhi84Sxr8o0DZHximQjlCOUI2QzItMzRDMC00N0Q1LTgyQ0EtMzI1MzhCRjNERTZDjQiIQbx0/QTRCNtpvjQTaZEcjpYFSkKHsPK+d1Nlnx6MuaDI/Xs21W7orysOeYPRRoDCCX/3ZtL61T3SHYfMkPeqXTJ4rloliGHsN7tuQXeI6OYAXXs8ysayP4VzpJyQEm+S0zvjkVLLtanQ5RDfQ1bnYq9ayu7L5HDJDNaKQhmhXmTdodwTlvwJRRyWgLL/GCuWWyAXEppy9Ta7PzpO76sb9c91ssScjDJY/Fw7TIPipleMgjjnHud1Os/NAihtTxTMWxS5XpiZbCh6DtvPwYyZXE54nsyhIekRvrixFQ0PeZinWpAkUAAAA=; domain=sharepoint.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly;FedAuth=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; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly;
```

If I copy and paste this information starting from the "rtFA=" part into the "Advanced REST client" chrome extension I get a successful reponse.

However when printing the entry

```
$lwp->cookie_jar->as_string()
```

In the result there are extra double quote characters. i.e.

```
Set-Cookie3:rtFa="UROIhi84Sxr8o0DZHximQjlCOUI2QzItMzRDMC00N0Q1LTgyQ0EtMzI1MzhCRjNERTZDjQiIQbx0/QTRCNtpvjQTaZEcjpYFSkKHsPK+d1Nlnx6MuaDI/Xs21W7orysOeYPRRoDCCX/3ZtL61T3SHYfMkPeqXTJ4rloliGHsN7tuQXeI6OYAXXs8ysayP4VzpJyQEm+S0zvjkVLLtanQ5RDfQ1bnYq9ayu7L5HDJDNaKQhmhXmTdodwTlvwJRRyWgLL/GCuWWyAXEppy9Ta7PzpO76sb9c91ssScjDJY/Fw7TIPipleMgjjnHud1Os/NAihtTxTMWxS5XpiZbCh6DtvPwYyZXE54nsyhIekRvrixFQ0PeZinWpAkUAAAA="; domain=sharepoint.com; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly;FedAuth="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"; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly;
```

If I copy and paste THIS information, again, starting from the "rtFA=" part into the "Advanced REST client" chrome extension I get an error 403 Forbidden error which is exactly what I get when I run the rest of my code after the

print $lwp->cookie_jar->as_string() . "\n";

statement.

How can I stop perl inserting these extra double quote (") marks which seem to be stopping my perl script from connecting to the website?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the result of `as_string` to get a cookie value. That's not meant for the wire, usually. Look at the `add_cookie_header` subroutine from [HTTP::Cookies](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookie) and notice that they don't use `as_string` to figure out anything. That does quote everything except the value though.

I think the first thing you need to consider is what you are giving to `HTTP::Cookies`. Maybe the `XML` in the variable name is just a bad name, but the data aren't XML. If you've messed up the data in *Result.txt*, your problem happens very early:

```
my $resultXML='C:\Docs\Result.txt';
my $url="https://[mydomain].sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo";
        
my $cookie_jar_obj = HTTP::Cookies->new();
$cookie_jar_obj->load( $resultXML );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. However I was not using the result of as_string. I was just printing it to see what it looked like after I got the error from the last print statement in my code above. It was then I noticed the extra double quotes and thought that was why my script was not connecting to the website. I have concluded that there is something wrong when adding the cookie from my file but I don't know what to use instead. I'll take a look at the add_cookie_header subroutine

Comment: You said "If I copy and paste THIS information, again, starting from the "rtFA=" part into the "Advanced REST client" chrome extension". That sure sounds like you are using the result of `as_string`.

Comment: Yes, but just in the chrome extension. I was using the extension for checking purposes only to try and figure out why my Perl script is not connecting to the website.